# Huge storage increase when executing a alter table query in Managed Instance Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have a table which consist of more than 2 million records in a azure managed instance database. When I'm trying to add columns to the table using alter command, storage space is increasing drastically while executing the query.

What may be the cause of this problem? And any solution to overcome this issue?

Thank you.

ALTER TABLE dbo.account SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.account
ADD
[ownerid] uniqueidentifier NULL,
[ownername] nvarchar(4000) NULL;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.accountHistory
ADD
[ownerid] uniqueidentifier NULL,
[ownername] nvarchar(4000) NULL;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.account
SET ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.accountHistory) ); this is the query

Comment: What is the exact code for the `ALTER` statement? Does it half a default value?

Comment: ALTER TABLE dbo.account SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.account
ADD
[ownerid] uniqueidentifier NULL,
[ownername] nvarchar(4000) NULL;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.accountHistory
ADD
[ownerid] uniqueidentifier NULL,
[ownername] nvarchar(4000) NULL;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.account SET
(
SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.accountHistory)   
); this is the query

Comment: Please edit the question to provide more information.

Comment: @SLNPerera Like Rohit mentioned, you should put edits in your original post, so they're more readable and everyone sees them. In any case, why are you turning off Temporal Tables to add those columns?...You don't need to do that, Temporal Tables will automatically add them to the history table for you. I don't think you can reconnect the history table and turn Temporal Tables back on without them (from what I recall, but I could be mistaken). I believe you'll get an error.

Comment: But I'm doing this process over a year using this alter query format. I didn't get this type of issue before. Are there any reason for this other than this?